# How does WHERE work with empty subqueries in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table of events with (indexed) columns `id : uuid` and `created : timestamp`.

I would like to fetch the 10 *oldest* events that were created *after* a given event was created. If the given event does not exist, then just the oldest 10 should be returned.

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM events 
WHERE created >= (
  SELECT created FROM events WHERE id = 'dab473dd-aaaa-4885-9717-e4463e2a555e' 
) 
ORDER BY created ASC
LIMIT 10
```

However, it does not work when the given id (in this example `dab473dd-aaaa-4885-9717-e4463e2a555e`) does not exist.

How should I go about this in Postgres?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [`COALESCE()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL), since this seems to give the shortest query:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM events 
    WHERE created >= COALESCE(
      (SELECT created FROM events WHERE id = 'dab473dd-aaaa-4885-9717-e4463e2a555e'),
      '-infinity'::TIMESTAMP
    )
    ORDER BY created ASC
    LIMIT 10
```

Note that this assumes that `created` is a `TIMESTAMP`.

[Scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) return `NULL` if the subquery returns an empty set of rows and hence `COALESCE()` skips to the sentinel.